# Move element in array

Tags: c++, arrays, std, stdvector

I have a 2d array of vectors of pointers to Entities in a game. The array represents a grid of game world to improve performance when detecting collisions. When an entity moves I check if it moves over to another grid-tile (of course) but this is where everything goes to hell. If I move the object in the array when it changes tile CPU goes to 100% instead of 8% and game physics no longer apply.

This is the update function where it stops working:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < xGridCount; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < yGridCount; j++)
        {
            for (auto it : grid[i][j])
            {

                it->update(); 


                //update gridpos
                if ((int) it->x/gridSize != i || (int) it->y/gridSize != j)
                {
                    grid[it->x/gridSize][it->y/gridSize].emplace_back(std::move(it));
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Declaration of grid array:

```
std::array<std::array<std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Entity>>, yGridCount>, xGridCount> grid;
```

The "update gridpos" is where it collapses. If I comment it out everything works as it should.

I have, of course, figured what I could do to fix it and I've thought of using the array *only* in the collision detection. But the thing about that would be that I would have to keep 2 pointers of every object, one for hit detection and one for updating/rendering and that doesn't sound like a good solution.

Why is it so CPU heavy?
And how else could I do it?

Comment: Instead of describing the declaration of `grid`, please *show it*.

Comment: Edited topic to show it @JoachimPileborg

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with the emplace_back(std::move(it)) expression?

Comment: Move it from a position in the grid to another @KristianDuske

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (auto it : grid[i][j])
```

`it` is a `shared_ptr`, and this produces a copy. Making a gratituous copy of a `shared_ptr` is a performance loss. (Usually `it` stands for "iterator", so I'm not sure why you called it `it` anyway.)

```
grid[it->x/gridSize][it->y/gridSize].emplace_back(std::move(it));
```

This moves the `shared_ptr` `it` into the vector for new tile, but since `it` is a copy, it doesn't do anything to the `shared_ptr` in old one. As a result, it's now in two grid tiles at once.

---

There seems to be some confusion: `std::move` (the one-argument version) doesn't move anything; it merely casts the argument to an rvalue to signal "the contents of this object can be moved". The `shared_ptr`/`unique_ptr` move constructors essentially move the ownership of the pointee, not the smart pointer object itself. The moved-from smart pointer (which would be in an empty state) will remain in the container it is in until you actually erase it from the container.

Comment: Okay, makes sense. Would changing it to unique_ptr also make sense?

Comment: "I'm not sure why you called it `it`" - because "it" is as good a word as any for "the thing we're dealing with at the moment".